# Pass parameter to VB script from text file

Tags: vb.net

I need to pass dates as parameter to vb script.
Initially I am doing this with the help of vbs file.

But now the requirement is to pass dates as arguments to vb script from a text file.

Any help on this please..

Comment: what have you tried? Please post your code, explain what is wrong, any error messages, then we can try to help

Comment: I tried many things but what is happening that the text file code is getting displayed on the command prompt,instead of executing.

Comment: Earlier the code was in vbs file so when I execute a file execute.bat which consist Date.vbs,makezip.vbs and mailsend.cmd.Now last two are working fine but Date.txt is not executing.I want to execute the code pasted below which is inside the Date.txt file......Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With objExcel
  .Workbooks.Open "C:\emailfetch\FetchEmails.xlsm"
  .Visible = True
  .Run "FolderTraverse",cLng(DateSerial(2014,3,1)),cLng(DateSerial(2014,3,4))
  .ActiveWorkbook.Close True
  .Quit
End With